# Azure parameter file cannot be found in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am implementing a Logic App in Visual Studio.
I created the Logic App which works properly and I can deploy it using VSTS.
But when I am adding a new ARM file (Test1_QA.parameters.json), I cannot find it in VSTS.

[image]

In VSTS I am using **Azure Resource Group Deployment** task.

Of course when I am deploying  directly from within VS by right click on the project, I can select the new file.
I searched the web but couldn't find anything. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you publish artifact through Publish Artifact task? (Path to publish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file properties in VS have a "Build Action" set to "Content"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i suppose you would need to commit the file and push it to VSTS.

generally you can do it by using these commands:

```
git add -a
git commit -m 'commit message'
git push
```

Comment: I have already committed to VSTS. When I queue the build definition, I can see the new file in the 's' folder but after I run the release, the file is not in 'a' folder. I suspect I must declare the new files in a resource json but it is not clear how.